# Problem with path 301 redirects in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We're trying to redirect a bunch of category URLs like this:

```
Redirect 301 /table/ https://www.example.com/abc/
Redirect 301 /table/accessoires/ https://www.example.com/def/
Redirect 301 /table/accessoires/tablecloth/ https://www.example.com/ghj/
```

The first redirect works correctly. But why do the other 2 don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order matters. The more specific rules should be first.

```
Redirect 301 /table/accessoires/tablecloth/ https://www.example.com/ghj/
Redirect 301 /table/accessoires/ https://www.example.com/def
Redirect 301 /table/ https://www.example.com/abc/
```